# Sending notifications with interval 1 minute using resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-messaging, resque

I'm trying to send notifications to user using GCM and resque. Currently it is sending the message to all users and it spiked the server because there are too many users. So what i'm trying to approach is sending the message to 1000 users for each minute.

Is there a way to set that up for resque?

I have one thing in mind where loop through all users, then batch the users for 1000. While still inside the loop make a Timeout for 60 seconds.
But i'm thinking this approach is bad.

Comment: Any reason you're not taking advantage of GCM Topics Messaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

1. find users in batches with index, therefore you can use index to calculate delayed time.
2. Use `wait` option to delay the job instead of timeout.

---

```
User.find_in_batches.with_index do |group, index|
  puts "Processing group ##{index}"
  GCMJob.set(wait: index.minutes).perform_later(group.ids) # each batch will have 60 seconds in between
end
```

---

```
class GCMJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(user_ids)
    users = User.where(id: user_ids)
    users.map(&:send_gcm_message)
  end
end
```